# Power BI Removing one of the duplicates

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a situation where the same Contract appears wrongly twice in the Revenue Data base where it should only appear once the revenue is recognized. and I need to remove the row that has Null value in "Revenue Recognized" field. How can i do that .

[Sample Data(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r93eY.png)

I could use "Group By" to identify the duplicate contracts in the "Contracts" field but not sure how to remove the wrong entry.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can trigger delete duplicate entry

1. Using group by with count > 1 and null check

   WITH DuplicateContracts AS ( SELECT Contracts
   FROM Revenues
   WHERE RevenueRecognized IS NULL
   GROUP BY Contracts
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

   DELETE FROM Revenues WHERE Contracts IN (SELECT Contracts FROM DuplicateContracts) AND RevenueRecognized IS NULL;
2. Using Window function

   WITH RankedContracts AS (
   SELECT *,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Contracts) AS ContractCount
   FROM Revenues )

   DELETE FROM RankedContracts WHERE RevenueRecognized IS NULL AND ContractCount > 1;

Hope That helps !!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, try this:

[image: PBI Desktop sample]

1. In PowerBI desktop, use the "Transform Data" button.
2. Navigate to your table
3. On the Revenue column, click the filter option (highlighted in the top of the column)
4. Deselect Null value.
   This should produce behind the Fx symbol:

   = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Revenue] <> "Null"))

With this answer, there are some things to consider though:

- You "Null" value looks like literal 'Null', therefore warning me it's not really Null. So I would want to check data-upstream if I were you where this Null is actually produced.